# NoMethodError: Undefined method 'post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am making some tests for an app using Rails 2.3.18

When running rake the first test fails.
The test file is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'add_item' do
    assert_equal 0, Item.find(:all).size
    post :add_item, :item => {:name => 'Name of item',
                              :comment => ''}
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to :action => 'index'
    assert_equal 1, Item.find(:all).size
  end
end
```

The line `post :add_item ...` is where an error occurs.

The error message is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for #<ItemTest:0x7f0645ce1790>
```

Researching this has thrown up several suggestions, none of which have worked.

1. Including 'actionpack' in the gemfile. This didn't make any difference.
2. using the line:
   `it "some test" do` before the test.
   This has changed the error to another NoMethodError saying that 'it' is undefined instead.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to post to a model object, that doesn't make any sense.  Should this be `class ItemControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase`?  What are you trying to test?

Comment: I am trying to test what happens when the 'add_item' page is given details for the item. At least it should be adding one more item to the given list. The first step is to post a new item. Which is done through the 'add_item' method in a controller page called manager_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should inherit from `ActionController::TestCase`, not `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. It's `ActionController::TestCase` that provides the `get`/`post`/etc methods for tests.